# Does task switching in concurrent code result in faster code than synchronous execution?

Tags: performance, concurrency

I understand that concurrency is not parallelism, but I believe that is my source of confusion about the speed of concurrency in environments that only use a single thread (go/node).

If everything is running in a single process, and a scheduler is constantly switching between different concurrent tasks wouldn't the overhead generated by this constant switching lead to slower execution of code than if everything was done synchronously?

I know that concurrency has it advantages when you want non-blocking code, for example a web server that switches between servicing thousands of requests instead of just focusing on one, and it shines in that regard; however, I've having difficulty understanding if it actually is faster, or if concurrency just **appears** to be faster.

Comment: Who says is faster? [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

Comment: @RemusRusanu I've always assumed it was faster until I took some time to think about it. I just want to know if I am right or wrong now.

Comment: Concurrent code is efficient when there are some IO-bound activities (e.g. sending to and receiving data from the network). Without concurrency your single thread has to wait doing nothing for the call to complete. Pure CPU-bound activities does not benefit from concurrency on a single thread (which may add unecessary overhead) but can benefit from multi-threading if the workload can be distributed across multiple CPU's working in parallel.

Comment: @MartinLiversage okay thank you. Exactly what I was wondering.

Comment: The advantage of async IO is thread it is thread-less. That saves memory and OS resources. It's the only way to solve, for instance, the C10M problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrent code is efficient when there are some IO-bound activities (e.g. sending to and receiving data from the network). Without concurrency your single thread has to wait doing nothing for the call to complete. Pure CPU-bound activities do not benefit from concurrency on a single thread (which may add unnecessary overhead) but can benefit from multi-threading if the workload can be distributed across multiple CPU's working in parallel.

Another advantage of async IO is thread it is threadless. That saves memory and OS resources. It's the only way to solve, for instance, the C10M problem.